# Why can't I initialize std::vector with list-initialization

Tags: c++, c++11

Why doesn't this work?

```
#include <vector>

struct A {
   template <typename T> void f(const std::vector<T> &) {}
};

int main() {

   A a;

   a.f({ 1, 2, 3 });

}
```

Comment: Because it can't derive the type information from a naked brace-list-initializer. `a.f<int>({1,2,3});` should work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You *can* initialize a `std::vector<T>` with list initialization. However, you cannot *deduce* the template argument `T` using a `std::vector<T>` in the argument list and passing the function something which isn't a `std::vector<T>`. For example, this works:

```
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
struct A {
   void f(const std::vector<T> &) {}
};

int main() {

    A<int> a;

   a.f({ 1, 2, 3 });

}
```